# Why my function is endless loop? How can ı stop after working

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

My Function never stop after working

I tried try catch, if() but I didn't

It is my vue code:

```
<template v-for="(event,index) in eventsMap[date]">

<v-menu :key="index" full-width offset-x>

<template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
```

It is my javascript code:

```
<v-flex>
  <template v-for="(event,index) in eventsMap[date]">
    <v-menu :key="index" full-width offset-x>
      <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">
        <div v-ripple v-bind:style="Styles3" v-on="on">{{ findID(event.UserNo) }}</div>
      </template>
      <template v-for="(event,index) in eventsMap[date]">
        <v-menu :key="index" full-width offset-x>
          <template v-slot:activator="{ on }">

function findID(val) {
  try {
    var params = {
      UserID: val
    }

    this.$http.post(auth.API_URL + 'api/Problems/User', params, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + auth.getAuthHeader()
      }
    }).then((response) => {
      this.userList = response.body
    }, (response) => {
      if (response.Status === true) {
        this.text1 = response.body.ResponseMessage
        this.snackbar = true
      } else {
        this.text1 = response.statusText
        this.snackbar = true
      }
    })

    return this.userList
  } catch (e) {
    alert(e);
  }
}
```

Thank you for help

I don't have error messages but this function never stops.

Comment: What does the logic look like for the function named `idbul`? Is that the same as `findID(val)`? If so, each function call is probably causing the template to update, and each update of the template is probably calling the function, thus the loop.

Comment: Yes it is, How can I use this structure?

Comment: Instead of calling findID from the template (`{{ findID(event.UserNo) }}`), you'll likely just want to access an existing variable (try something like `{{ myVar }}` instead). Right now it's not really clear to me what the intent of your code is. If you're trying to display this.userList (maybe it's a list of users?) then you might need to v-for through it. In any case, you'll want findID() to be called under a certain condition, as opposed to in the template, where it gets called each time the template is updated. Instead try simply calling it right after you define it, and go from there.